# How to insert from csv to dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Dynamo db have one table employees primary key as id

data.csv is below which  uploaded in the `csvdynamo` bucket

bucket_name = csvdynamo

```
id,name,co
20,AB,PC
21,CD,PC
22,EF,MC
23,GH,MC
```

Need to insert above csv into dynamodb

psuedo code

```
for emp in employees:
    emp_data= emp.split(',')
    print (emp_data)

    try:
        table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "emp_id": int(emp_data[0]),
                "Name": emp_data[1],
                "Company": emp_data[2]
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
          pass
```

Comment: any alternate way is also helpful

Comment: "Full code which is not working" - can you please clarify what do you mean? Do you get any error messages, timeouts, access denies ...?

Comment: @Marcin any alternate way without calling event['Records'] will be helpful. Deleting full code as it is unnecessary

Comment: @Marcin Any alternate way us also helpful

Comment: Sorry, hadn't had time to look into it. I will try a bit later today. Meantime, maybe someone else will be able to assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of a lambda function which **works**, as I **verified** it using my own function, csv file and dynamodb. I think the code is self-explanatory. It should be a **good start** towards your end use-case.

```
          import boto3
          import json
          import os

          bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
          csv_key = os.environ['CSV_KEY_NAME'] # csvdynamo.csv
          table_name = os.environ['DDB_TABLE_NAME']
          
          # temprorary file to store csv downloaded from s3
          tmp_csv_file = '/tmp/' + csv_key

          s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
          db_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name)

          def save_to_dynamodb(id, name, co):

            return db_table.put_item(
                Item={
                  'emp_id': int(id),
                  'Name': name,
                  'Company': co
                })

          def lambda_handler(event, context):

              s3.meta.client.download_file(
                            bucket_name, 
                            csv_key, 
                            tmp_csv_file)

              with open(tmp_csv_file, 'r') as f:

                next(f) # skip header

                for line in f:

                  id, name, co = line.rstrip().split(',')

                  result = save_to_dynamodb(id, name, co)

                  print(result)

              return {'statusCode': 200}
```

Comment: can you check once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351210/how-to-extract-the-elements-from-csv-to-json-in-s3

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB needs to be told the type of field being inserted.

From [`put_item()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item), the format for `Item` is:

```py
    Item={
        'string': {
            'S': 'string',
            'N': 'string',
            'B': b'bytes',
            'SS': [
                'string',
            ],
            'NS': [
                'string',
            ],
            'BS': [
                b'bytes',
            ],
            'M': {
                'string': {'... recursive ...'}
            },
            'L': [
                {'... recursive ...'},
            ],
            'NULL': True|False,
            'BOOL': True|False
        }
    },
```

Therefore, you would need something like:

```py
        table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "emp_id":  {'N': emp_data[0]},
                "Name":    {'S': emp_data[1]},
                "Company": {'S': emp_data[2]}
            }
        )
```

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618932/how-to-read-content-from-the-s3-bucket-as-url

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for those who just want to import a csv file that is locally on their computer to a DynamoDB table. (I just took the script from @Marcin and modified it a little bit, leaving out the S3 bucket code and making it more general.)

```
import boto3


csv_file_path = "your-csv-file.csv"
table_name = "your-dynamodb-table-name"
db_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name)
line_seperator = ';'


def save_to_dynamodb(column_names, values):
    item = dict()

    for idx, column_name in enumerate(column_names):
        item[column_name.lower()] = values[idx]

    return db_table.put_item(
        Item=item
    )


def handler():

    with open(csv_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:

        column_names = next(f).strip("\n").split(line_seperator)

        for line in f:
            values = line.strip("\n").split(line_seperator)

            result = save_to_dynamodb(column_names, values)

            print(result)

    print("FINISHED IMPORT")


handler()
```